# assumptions of REML

Tags: likelihood, reml

In Patterson and Thompson 1971, $L$ is the log-likelihood of $y$
$$
L = const - \frac{1}{2}log |H| - \frac{1}{2}n log (\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y - X\alpha)'H^{-1}(y-Xa)
$$

They consider the transformations $Sy$ and $Qy$ with respective log-likelihoods $L'$ and $L''$ and the assumptions:

1. $S$ is of rank $n-t$ and $Q$ is of rank $t$
2. $Sy$ and $Qy$ are statistically independent

From these assumptions it follows that $L=L' + L''$. Can someone give a formal proof? Of course 2. explains the additive part on the left, but the equality is not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: If you give us the full reference of Patterson and Thompson 1971 (including page numbers) then we don't have to look it up.

Comment: Patterson, H. D.; Thompson, R. (1971). "Recovery of inter-block information when block sizes are unequal". Biometrika 58 (3): 545. doi:10.1093/biomet/58.3.545   section 3